# Read EDID direct from monitor NO drivers

Tags: c#, windows, winpe, edid

I got this [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) project where I'm trying to extract the [edid](/questions/tagged/edid) directly from the monitor. 
The goal is to make a application which can run on [winpe](/questions/tagged/winpe) without any drivers installed.
I know it is possible to get the information with the registration database or [wmi](/questions/tagged/wmi), but this is not possible in this project because it won't provide the correct information without drivers installed. We got this attached code that works, but I guess it asks the drivers for the resolutions, because it won't work when we try on a [winpe](/questions/tagged/winpe) installation.
Here's the code that can display the resolutions, when the drivers are installed..

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern bool EnumDisplaySettings([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string lpszDeviceName, int iModeNum, out Program.DEVMODE lpDevMode);
public static List<Tuple<int, int>> GetScreenResolutions()
{
    List<Tuple<int, int>> list = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
    try
    {
        int num = 0;
        Program.DEVMODE dEVMODE;
        while (Program.EnumDisplaySettings(null, num++, out dEVMODE))
        {
            Tuple<int, int> item = Tuple.Create<int, int>(dEVMODE.dmPelsWidth, dEVMODE.dmPelsHeight);
            if (!list.Contains(item))
            {
                list.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Could not get screen resolutions.");
    }
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to P/Invoke to the [native SetupAPI](http://thetweaker.wordpress.com/2011/11/13/reading-monitor-physical-dimensions-or-getting-the-edid-the-right-way/). Haven't tested the code in the link on winpe, though.

Comment: As far as I can see your example uses the registry to read the EDID, which I have already tried without success.

Comment: Did you search the registry yourself?  The exact registry path varies greatly among systems, and SetupAPI is the official way of retrieving the right one.

Comment: I did use the SetupAPI to find the registry path, but when dealing with WinPE you can't get any usefull information from the registry because the drivers don't provide any information.

Comment: Jumping on an old conversation here - I was able to get your setup api code working in c# using pinvoke, but I can only get the monitor dimensions. Is there any guide as to how to interpret the EDID byte array using c# or even c++? I don't understand enough about bit shifting to understand the official EDID documentation